Calibration Set Size and Details
I know in practice we often do a traditional 80-20 split for our train-test splits. However, for the purpose of probability calibration, we often need an additional calibration split. How should this be done, and what is the optimal size typically for a calibration set? Should I take an arbitrary 10% split from the training data to reserve for probability calibration?

Instead of allocating a proportion of data to a calibration set, one can use a CV method of probability calibration where out of fold sets are used to calibrate the probabilities.
